# Is there a feature in Mutants & Masterminds 3e that is mechanically similar to Evasion in D&D 5e?

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In *Mutants and Masterminds*, much like in many versions of D&D, Area of Attack abilities allow you a dodge check to take half effect. That's all fine and dandy, but I'm trying to create a character who can see the tiniest movement in his opponents and moves in advance to make certain he's not where the attack is going to be when it goes off, which results in a very high dodge / parry and a very low toughness.

This works fine for single target attacks, but for AoE attacks, even when he makes his save, he's still looking at an injury, which doesn't really work for the idea of fighting-by-avoidance.

I'm trying to make a power that works similar to evasion in 5e, which reads:

> **When you are subjected to an effect that allows you to make a Dexterity saving throw to take only half damage, you instead take no damage if you succeed on the saving throw**, and only half damage if you fail.

I don't care about the half damage when you fail part, if he gets hit, he gets hit hard, but I want to figure out a way to avoid taking half effect if I succeed the dodge.

It seems, however, that *Mutants and Masterminds* doesn't really have this option. I've looked at immunity (which lacks an AoE immunity), and doing something like a Leaping Reaction on Dodge to physically move out of the way, but I might be over-complicating things.

Comment: As a historical note, in 2nd edition M&M the Evasion feat did this exact thing (no damage on successful Reflex save against an Area effect). I wasn't able to find anything in the 3rd edition materials to this effect but I am more familiar with 2nd edition so I will hold off on posting as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take an Enhanced Trait: Toughness power with the Impervious quality, with a sufficiently high Limited modifier specifically calling out you're only immune to damage from Dodge checks that you have succeeded. Note that per p.135 on Partial Modifiers, you will need at least as many ranks in the power increasing Toughness as you would in the Impervious stat (and thus, defeat the intent at being defensive by dodging).

Alternatively, consider the "Impervious" modifier for an Enhanced Trait: Dodge power.

> Impervious is primarily intended for Toughness resistance
> checks, to handle characters immune to a certain threshold
> of damage, **but it can be applied to other defenses with the
> GM’s permission**, to reflect characters with certain reliable
> capabilities in terms of resisting particular effects or hazards.

Having a certain degree of ranks in Impervious defense makes the character immune to the effect. For example, a Grenade is a piece of equipment that counts as a Area Damage 5 power. So having 10 ranks in Impervious Dodge would make your character immune to a grenade.

In the end though, the Impervious modifier is what you're looking for. If you want to be able to buy this cheap, then bundle it with Limited so that it only applies when you have succeeded on the test.

It is worth pointing out that the whole "80 ranks in Immunity" to be Immune to Toughness is there to be equal to having Enhanced Toughness 40 and Impervious 40, thus being able to ignore a rank 20 attack. As long as you don't need your character to successfully evade a nuke, you don't need to start from there.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it seems the most useful. Considering I'm only going for 'immunity' if I've actually dodged, the actual power I need to resist will likely never be above 5 (for a rank 10 attack that was resisted), so an Impervious Dodge, limited to AoE and only after resisting seems like it's going to be the thing that fits both thematically and mechanically to the evasion feat.

Answer (score 4):

### Similar? Yes. What you want? Not immediately.

The Evasion advantage exists, granting a circumstance bonus (+2 or +5) on rolls to Dodge area attacks. This is similar to the Evasion class feature in various iterations of D&D. However, as you noticed, this does not prevent the M&M character from having to resist the effect.

Also note that Perception range Area will ignore these ideas, since characters don't get to dodge those.

A few mechanical solutions come to mind.

1. Immunity
2. Feature
3. reaction movement

**Immunity:** Described on page 113 of the Hero's Handbook, Immunity has a number of possible effects and modifiers. For the described effect, you'd want 110 ranks of Immunity (resisted by Toughness, resisted by Fortitude), with Limited (only Area Effects) and Limited (only after successful Dodge resistance). You'll need to discuss the appropriateness of those limitations with the Game Master, who may require you to combine them into a single Limited or expand them into one or two more Limited modifiers. Personally, I would allow those two modifiers, which alters the cost of those 110 ranks from 110 points to 37-ish points. 
If you only wanted to be able to evade damage, then you'd only need 80 ranks, at a cost of 27 points.

**Feature:** Your Game Master may decide that this is better described by the Feature power (pages 108 and 109). Note that Feature provides *samples*, not an exhaustive list. Also note that, like the Benefit advantage, a particular Feature might require more than one rank of the power. Your Game Master may decide that negating area effects with a successful Evasion roll is a rank 5 Feature. This option is significantly cheaper but less reliably balanced.

**Reaction Movement:** A movement power (Speed, Flight, Teleport, Burrowing, etc.) with the Reaction action and a Limited that restricts it to Area attacks that you've successfully dodged (about half as useful as simply moving when area attacks include you). 
 You'll have a limited movement range, so you have an upper limit of areas you can dodge, based upon your power Rank; and you won't be able to completely dodge if there isn't an unaffected area to dodge to. But at 1 / rank for Reaction (area attacks) Speed Limited (successful Dodge), two ranks would be enough to dodge a 60' radius.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In earlier editions (1e to 2e), that's exactly what Evasion did, with a second rank giving you half ranks of the effect even on a missed save. 3e decided to break from its d20 roots and do something different, a circumstance bonus to the Dodge check. As others have covered, by the rules, you'd have to buy a very broad Immunity to Toughness/Will/Fortitude/etcetera and then Limit it to Area effects, and then make it Resistable such that you have to make your Dodge save.

Or, if your GM is cool, with it, you just import the earlier editions' Feat and call it an Advantage, but that is not RAW.